# Is wchar_t just a typedef of unsigned short?

Tags: c++, c, unsigned, short, wchar-t

for example, does:

```
wchar_t x;
```

translate to:

```
unsigned short x;
```

Comment: Marlon, the answer depends on whether you ask about C or C++. Do you want to know one of these or both?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In short: in C may be in C++ no.

Widely. C defines wchar_t as typedef but in Unix it is generally 4 bytes (so generally not short) and in Windows 2 so it may be short.

Under C++ it is unique built-in type like `char` or `int`, so you can legally overload `void foo(short x)` and `void foo(wchar_t x)`

Answer (score 18):

For anyone else who may come across this answer because function calls in your Visual Studio project won't link, despite both parties taking `wchar_t` (or a comparable type, such as `LPCTSTR` with UNICODE #defined), and when you DUMPBIN the library's exports the function takes `const unsigned short *`, be aware that VS allows you to switch off `wchar_t` as a built-in type. If someone changes this in a library, and you don't hit the same compiler switch in your project, it will not link.

This option can be changed under "Project Properties>C/C++/Language/Treat WChar_t as Builtin type", it can also be changed via the "/Zc" option.

Answer (score 12):

For C, `wchar_t` is a `typedef`. Whether it is a synonym for `unsigned int`, whether it is an unsigned type at all, or whether it is 4 bytes, is implementation-defined.

In C++, `wchar_t` is a distinct built-in type. Here, too, its size and signedness is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

wchar_t isn't required by the standard to be unsigned. It can also be signed.  And there must be another type of the same size; but the standard doesn't explicitly say that that other type must be short.

> "the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements as one of the other integral types, called its underlying type" (C++98 §3.9.1).

In C compilers this is a typedef, usually defined in stddef.h

Comment: Note `sizeof(wchar_t)` == 2 or 4 and it dependent on platform. Generally only windows `wchar_t` has 16 bits.

Comment: IIRC, AIX has also a 16 bits wchar_t and some embedded platforms have sizeof(wchar_t) == 1

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.  It translates to 'a wide character.'  Making any assumptions about what that *happens to be* on a particular platform is incorrect, and defeats the *entire purpose* of having a wchar_t in the first place.

The point of using an abstraction is to separate the semantic meaning of the type from its underlying representation.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily; it could be a 4-byte quantity, or indeed any other size chosen by the implementation.

It depends on the compiler.

Comment: ... but in order to be C++ standards compliant it would never be a `typedef`.

Comment: @dalle (and Artyom): yes, but the question asks about a typedef so it must be about C.  The tags actually omitted the language (I've added C now), but the inference is clear.

Comment: @Jonathan: No, the question asked _whether_ `wchar_t` is a `typedef`. That `C` tag is yours, not Marlon's. The correct answer would be _Yes_ for C, but _No_, for C++.

Comment: @Jonathan, I removed C tag, because it is not clear for the question that he asks about C, so I assume that the author should clarify if this is C only question or not.

Comment: @Artyom: OK...I think there are two subtly different but valid interpretations of the question, and we're tackling the two different versions. Version 1 is "Is wchar_t a typedef, and if so is it a typedef equivalent to unsigned short" - which every one else is assuming.  Version 2 is "Given that wchar_t is a typedef, is it a typedef of unsigned short". Version 1 allows for confusion with C++; version 2 does not (because wchar_t is not a typedef in C++ so the question can't be about C++). It seemed 'obvious' to me that it was version 2; clearly, others see version 1 as more plausible.