# Why am I presented with, "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'WORD [129]' to 'LPOLESTR'" after converting from VS2003 to VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, type-conversion

Converting an old vs2003 project to vs2010, and I've stumbled on one error:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'WORD [129]' to 'LPOLESTR'
```

Can anyone provide me with a hint as to what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Anyone what? Have a cookie? I do, but I'm not going to share.

Comment: It would help to see the code that produced the error.

Comment: Posting the relevant line and some context may help the diagnosis quite a bit... in the meantime, -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you didn't post any code, so I'm gonna just assume you have a wide-character string defined as,

```
WORD wszMyAwesomeStringThatsGonnaBePassedToAnAPIatSomePoint[129] = "Booga!";
```

See, in VS2005, MS [gets with the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395514/is-wchar-t-just-a-typedef-of-unsigned-short) and makes wchar_t a built-in type. Prior to that, it was just a typedef for... `unsigned short`. Which was *fine* for your purposes, since both WORD* and LPOLESTR were *also* just aliases for `unsigned short*`.

But now, wchar_t is a built-in type, and LPOLESTR is defined - assuming you're not compiling with OLE2ANSI defined - as `__RPC_string wchar_t*`... So your code breaks.

If you're already typing angrily, "U LIE!!! I DON'T USE `WORD` ANYWHERE!!!", *stop* - you may very well be using a *different* typedef or even #define that eventually results in your variable being defined as an array of `WORD`s. Maybe you're using some huge complicated framework that precompiles XML into structures containing WORD arrays; maybe someone else wrote the code for you and you've never even looked at it.

But since you didn't post any code showing us how you declare the string in question, I cannot say.

Comment: Even before VS2005 (at least in VS2003) it was possible to make it treat `wchar_t` as a builtin type (IIRC there was a `/Zsomething` option).

Comment: Yeah, it was a compiler option, but AFAIK it was either turned off by *default*, or off for projects converted from earlier versions of VS.

Comment: Sure, it was just some gratuitous nitpickery. :) I actually gave you my +1 (I too was thinking about something like that, my first thought was about conflicting declarations of the all-uppercase `WCHAR_T`).

Comment: By the way, IIRC it was off by default even for new projects, maybe they weren't sure to have updated all the documentation/the system headers.

Comment: Yeah, I *suspect* they didn't have all the system headers updated to use char / wchar_t behind the scenes, but it could just as well have been they didn't want to break internal code for folks upgrading (I knew a team that stuck with VS *5* until fairly recently because they didn't care to fix all the little things that broke when upgrading).