# wchar_t is unsigned or signed

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, wchar-t

In this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374131.aspx) `unsigned wchar_t` is `typedef`ed as `WCHAR`. But I cant find this kind of typedef in my SDK `winnt.h` or mingw `winnt.h`.

`wchar_t` is signed or unsigned?

I am using WINAPIs in C language.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395514/is-wchar-t-just-a-typedef-of-unsigned-short

Comment: I think that page is just incorrect. The library *once upon a time* used to use  `unsigned short` when the compiler didn't have a built in `wchar_t` type. Guess the `unsigned` was just left there by mistake when changing to `wchar_t`.

Comment: Signed or unsigned, you shouldn't be using it. See utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @Pavel: In general, sure, but when you need to write glue code, or compiler tests, or string decoders for a debugger, or any number of other valid use cases you don't have a choice but to use `wchar_t`. Blanket absolutes tend not to be very helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The signedness of `wchar_t` is unspecified. The standard only says (3.9.1/5):

> Type `wchar_t` shall have the same size, signedness, and alignment requirements (3.11) as one of the other integral types, called its *underlying type*.

(By contrast, the types `char16_t` and `char32_t` are expressly unsigned.)

Comment: The [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367308(v=vs.85).aspx) seems to define it as unsigned though.

Comment: @netcoder: "unspecified" doesn't mean that nobody is allowed to define it. It just means that the standard doesn't mandate either signedness.

Comment: Yeah I know what the standard says, and I know how it works. The question is tagged `winapi` though, so I think this extra bit of info is still useful.

Comment: @netcoder yeah its useful though. Thanks. Have a look at the link in my post.

Comment: @user1317084: Is your question about C, or about how WinAPI implements certain implementation-defined aspects of C? It would be nice if you could clarify that.

Comment: Do you know if gcc's flags `-funsigned-char` or `-fsigned-char` affect it? In other words, any way to control its signedness?

Comment: @Antonio: I'm afraid I don't know, nor does the GCC documentation seem to describe it. Maybe ask on the GCC mailing lists?

Comment: @Antonio, those flags only affect `char`, I'm pretty sure you can't change whether  `wchar_t` is signed.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware the type will vary in length by platform.

Windows uses UTF-16 and a wchar_t is 2 bytes.  Linux uses a 4 byte wchar_t.

Comment: On most of the Linux systems I've seen, `wchar_t` is a 32-bit type, presumably meant for UTF-32 data.

Comment: Fixed.  It's been a few years since I worked with Unicode - I thought i remembered Linux using UTF-8, but if so, why have a four byte wchar_t?

Comment: Most modern Linux systems *do* use UTF-8 normally.  That's what `char` is for.  A 32-bit `wchar_t` is useful for UTF-32 where you want a fixed-width encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The standard may not specify whether `wchar_t` is signed or unsigned, but Microsoft does.  Even if your non-Microsoft compiler disagrees, the Windows API will be using this definition from [/Zc:wchar_t (wchar_t Is Native Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type?view=msvc-170):

> Microsoft implements `wchar_t` as a two-byte **unsigned** value. It maps to the Microsoft-specific native type `__wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Type WCHAR, not wchar_t, is defined on MSDN as the following:

```
   #if !defined(_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
    typedef unsigned short WCHAR;
    #else
    typedef wchar_t WCHAR;
    #endif
```

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar*

So you could conclude that its defined as unsigned on windows?

Answer (score -2):

I just tested on several platforms, with no optimisation.

```
1) MinGW (32-bit) + gcc 3.4.4:
---- snip ----
#include<stdio.h>
#include<wchar.h>
const wchar_t BOM = 0xFEFF;
int main(void)
{
    int c = BOM;
    printf("0x%08X\n", c+0x1000);
    return 0;
}
---- snip ----
```

It prints `0x00010EFF`. `wchar_t` is unsigned.
Corresponding assembly code says `movzwl _BOM, %eax`. Not `movSwl`, but `movZwl`.

```
2) FreeBSD 11.2 (64-bit) + clang 6.0.0:
---- snip ----
#include<stdio.h>
#include<wchar.h>
const wchar_t INVERTED_BOM = 0xFFFE0000;
int main(void)
{
     long long c = INVERTED_BOM;
     printf("0x%016llX\n", c+0x10000000LL);
     return 0;
}
---- snip ----
```

It prints `0x000000000EFF0000`. `wchar_t` is signed.
Corresponfing assembly code says, `movq $-131072, -16(%rbp)`. The 32-bit `0xFFFE0000` is promoted to 64-bit signed `-131072`.

3) Same code as 2), on RedHat (version unknown) + gcc 4.4.7: It again prints `0x000000000EFF0000`. `wchar_t` is signed.

I tested neither the `printf`'s implementation nor WinAPI's `WCHAR` definition, but the behaviors of compiler-builtin `wchar_t` type (no specification about its signedness on any header file) and C-to-ASM compiler engine.

Note that the compilers on 1) and 3) are provided by the same vendor, namely the GNU Project. The answer definitely depends on platforms. (Would somebody test on Visual C++?)